# Registration and login on single form

Tags: sign-in

I am working on an application, where i would like the user to first register and than log in to the application.

Can i make the user perform both actions from a single form i.e. as soon as he registers he may be logged in or go for separate forms for both the actions

Comment: So you don't plan for verification.

Comment: Sure, just label the button as `Register and Login!`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just make one form. This makes it so much simpler, because I sometimes get frustrated on larger multi-part sign up systems, such as Microsoft's huge logon, that is so long and is very frustrating, because it forces the user to go through so many steps that could had just been one slightly larger page.